# oracle apex select list

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle Apex 4.2. I have a select list. I'm trying to create a dynamic action that should be simple enough but I'm not sure how to do it. I'm also trying to insert selected value in database using plsql code but there some error occur.
lets say
 How would I make this dynamic action?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you post your code and expected results to clarify what you're asking and make your question more accessible?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create item `PX_SELECTLIST`
2. Create dynamic action

> Event = Change
>
> Selection Type = Item(s)
>
> Item(s) = `PX_SELECTLIST`

3. Create true action "Execute PL/SQL Code"

> PL/SQL Code = Your PL/SQL code with begin end block - reference item value by `:PX_SELECTLIST` within the code.
>
> Page Items to Submit = `PX_SELECTLIST`
>
> Page Items to Return = leave it blank

4. Test it - each time value in `PX_SELECTLIST` changes the dynamic action is fired and PL/SQL code is executed.

Additionaly I suggest reading Oracle APEX docs - http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/cloud/schema/42/dynactions/dynactions.html